# Young tableaux - column group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles, young-tableaux

I am studying young tableaux and at one point in a demonstration the author states that
$$C_{\pi t} = \pi C_{t}\pi^{-1}$$
where $C_{t}$ is a subgroup of $S_{n}$ consisting of permutations which only permutes the elements within each column of the tableau $t$. I can't understand this statement, someone can help me? Thak you.

Comment: I think $C_t$ consists of those $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $k$ and $\sigma(k)$ are always in the same column of the tableau $t$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The definition of $C_{t}$ is the one that I wrote, but I don't know how prove this: $C_{\pi t} = \pi C_{t}\pi^{-1}$

Comment: See also the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295621/what-is-the-centralizer-of-the-young-symmetrizer).